# Instantiate n times a given module

Tags: verilog

As a continuation to [my previous question](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/32440/stress-testing-an-fpgas-power-supply), is  there a way, in Verilog, to instantiate `n` times a given module, without having to use `n` different lines:

```
myModule instance1();
myModule instance2();
myModule instance3();
...
```

Can I do "batch" instantiation in Verilog?

Comment: Can you bring over the required information from your previous question if it is needed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Ok, found it. Search [here](http://www.inno-logic.com/resourcesTips.html) for the "generate statement":

> Verilog 2001 `generate statement` allow to either instantiating
> multiple modules without typing them so many times or instantiating
> modules conditionally. You can use *if-else* to conditionally
> instantiate the modules. Also, if you want to instantiate the same
> module multiple times then better use *for loop*. This will save you
> lot of time.

**UPDATE**

this link is viable 4.27.2023

http://web.archive.org/web/20120723031726/http://www.inno-logic.com:80/resourcesTips.html

The following code will do the job:

```
genvar i;
generate for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) begin
    myModule instance();
end endgenerate
```

Comment: If you are going to write an answer, include a bit more detail. When that link goes dead, your answer will have no value.

Comment: For the record, VHDL also has a generate statement.

Comment: This answer doesn't work on Vivado 2013. It just instantiates one instance of myModule with the name "instance". Is there another solution? genvar i; generate for (i = 0; i < n; i = i + 1) begin myModule instance(); end endgenerate